# Consider as one

Tags: shorthand

Is it correct to say "all files are considered as one" as a synonym for "all files are considered as if they were one"?

*Edit:* As for the requested context: There is a software system that processes files. Files can be processed as single items or as a group of several files. What I want to express succinctly is that one can view the group-case as the one-file case where all files are "united" in the sense that all their content is to be "considered as one".

Comment: Does the answer have to be specific to *files* (and by *files* do you mean paper files or electronic computer files) or can it apply to any group of individual items? That information might produce a difference answer, but, more importantly, would also determine what analogies could be used.

Comment: No, that's just the usage context; files are electronic ones. Btw, I'm aware that even the long form is formally not _per se_ meaningful. It is to mean "as if the content of all files were pasted into one file" - but that is a semantic sophistery. Stated differently, if there were a concept of transforming several files into one, would it then be understandable when using the shorthand? I hope this makes the intention of my question clear.

Comment: Provide the broader context. Cite the source if possible.

Comment: only vicars use the latter

Comment: I don't know your whole context ... But you have to be specific and unambiguous if you're writing a technical text. I think that "all files considered as one" is not the same than "as if the content of all files were pasted into one file".  I'll keep the last sentence and omit the first.

Comment: Yes of course, "all files are considered as one" means exactly the same as ”all files are considered as if they were one" but at the same time, neither expression could ever be useful.

What were you really asking, please?